# An app that pops up on top of any other app on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example, the built-in alarm clock app launches when it's time to ring (it doesn't just show a notification) even when another app is running.

Comment: You can not, the iOS SDk does not allow this.

Comment: Alarm Clock is a native app, IMO, iOS won't allow any other app to show from nowhere in another app. that'll disturb the UX. However you could use local notification as banner [on top] or alert to show your update.

Answer (score 1):

At WWDC 14 Apple showed off the Extensibility feature. You shouldn't be able to do it on iOS 7 but in the future(iOS 8) you can use the extensibility in third party applications.

For more information read the mashable blog : http://mashable.com/2014/06/02/apple-ios-extensibility/

Comment: Extensibility is back compatible with iOS 7 IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Not on an iOS device :D.

Only 1 app can be presented on the screen at one time.

Maybe in iOS 8 with split screen feature perhaps?

Although that isn't quite exactly what you want.